# Global destroy method for all the bean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, destroy

I'm working on a spring project & there is a requirement to apply a functionality on destroy of each bean.
I just want to know that is there's any global destroy method that gets called whenever any object is destroyed instead of specifying the destroy method in all beans.

Thanks.

Comment: there may be hundreds of different beans will be in context, why do you want to act on 'destroy' of each of them

Comment: there's a map maintained in the application for the objects that are not destroyed. And on destroy of any object the same should be removed from the map.

Comment: why is this question being downvoted? There are dozens of reasons I could see for adding listener hooks for when any bean is destroyed. In my case, I have a pub sub that any bean can register to using annotations. When any bean is destroyed I want to unregister that bean if it's currently registered with the pub sub. Without this, I have to add the same destroy method on every bean in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the bean class from a super class where it contains destroy method.

Answer (score 0):

[DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/DestructionAwareBeanPostProcessor.html) looks to do the trick. You can inspect the bean and the bean name to do your processing